# Bind Tree view to object and not to List<object>

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm

This is maybe a very simple question, still I don't know how to solve this.

I have a model in my MVVM application which I want to bind to a tree view. However I can only bind the tree view to a list of items (or in my case an ObservableCollection).
This is the model I currently use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an group a character can belong to.
/// </summary>
public class OrganisationBase : ModelBase<OrganisationBase>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name.
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// The parent organization.
    /// </summary>
    private ObservableCollection<OrganisationBase> parentOrganizations;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the organization.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(p => p.Name);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parent organization.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<OrganisationBase> ParentOrganizations
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentOrganizations;
        }

        set
        {
            this.parentOrganizations = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(p => p.ParentOrganizations);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is: How can I bind this model to my tree view without using Observable collections. I want to do this, because there is no need for an ObservableCollection since every Organisation can only have one parent.

Or, how can I bind the following code to my tree view:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an group a character can belong to.
/// </summary>
public class OrganisationBase : ModelBase<OrganisationBase>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name.
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// The parent organization.
    /// </summary>
    private OrganisationBase parentOrganizations;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the organization.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        set
        {
            this.name = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(p => p.Name);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parent organization.
    /// </summary>
    public OrganisationBase ParentOrganizations
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentOrganizations;
        }

        set
        {
            this.parentOrganizations = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(p => p.ParentOrganizations);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the tree view I currently use:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Character.CharacterAllegiances.MemberOf}">
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
              Value="True" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ParentOrganizations}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Note: The Organisation property is part of a character model. Still when I use ObservableCollections everything displays fine. However as asked above I want to discard this ObservableCollections.

Greetings
Ruhrpottpatriot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreeView expects a collection of items in order to build its nodes, this is obviously the right way and quite self explanatory.

Binding the treeview to a single object will only work if that object exposes itself as a collection, e.g. implements `IEnumerable` that way the treeview will use the `IEnumerable` implementation to fill the data.

Alternatively you could just bind to a collection against the object e.g.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding object.SomeCollection}" />
```

Comment: Ok, It seems that I can only bind to something that exposes IEnumerator. Thanks for the clarification. I'll rethink the means of storing that information, maybe I'll come up with a better system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HierarchicalDataTemplate.

[image: Bind folder objects to a tree view] [image: Bind file objects to a tree view]

To bind data (e.g. both folders and files as above), you can refer to this post:
[WPF Treeview: data binding of heterogeneous types of data using CompositeCollection class](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/wpf-treeview-data-binding-of-heterogeneous-types-of-data-datatemplate-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate/)